# Junit Spy Mockito Тестирование

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Всем привет,учу java, есть задание протестировать с помощью Mockito.spy void метод который вызывает другие методы.Не получается правильно протестировать. Подскажите пожалуйста на примере как правильно это сделать )

```
public void menu() {
        do {
            menuPrint();
            switch (choice) {
            case "1":
                choise1();
                break;

            case "2":
                print(mesege2);
                break;
            }
        } while (!exit);

private void choise1() {
        print(mesage);
        methodCall()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14582339/mockito-how-to-mock-void-method-with-output-argument

Comment: Во первых ваш код не компилируется, вы забыли скобочки. Во вторых покажите что у вас получилось и в чем конкретно проблема.

Comment: Для тестирования методы должны получать параметры и возвращать значения.. не должно быть такого чтобы `void menu()` брал значение `choice` из "космоса" это должен быт входящий параметр. Методы должны зависеть только от входящих параметров. Глядя на код можно сказать, что `menuPrint();` ничего не делать, так же как и `choise1();`